# IntelliJ thinks package and file path do not match

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have imported a sizable enterprise project into IntelliJ but one particular package in one module is experiencing an issue. IntelliJ gives the error "Package name "X" does not correspond to the file path" when opening any class in this package and as a result refuses to acknowledge the classes as existing when I try to import them elsewhere. It has no problem with other packages at the same level in the module, the folder is visible in the project explorer window to the left and using "Show in Explorer" happily brings up the correct place in the file path. IntelliJ's automatic solution suggests setting the file path to "", suggesting it can't see the folder at all

I can temporarily fix the issue by deleting and then reimporting the module, but as soon as I restart IntelliJ the problem is back. This also removes the dependencies on this module from others and as about 25 other modules depend on this one, it is time-consuming to read these so it's not a long term solution.

I have tried using the Invalidate Caches command but with no success.

Comment: Have you ever tried to mark the corresponding folder as source directory? For example, `asd/com/stackoverflow/Test.java` is in package `com.stackoverflow`, mark folder `asd` as source directory.

Comment: if you use mvn or gradle, after a manual reimport of the module, i would try regenerating the intellij project files using the mvn plugin. This would generate a clean new project file and may help

Comment: It's probably a case-sensitivity issue. What are the actual names of the packages and of the folders?

Comment: I have indeed tried marking the appropriate folder as source, but it did not help
@JBNizet If it was case sensitivity the automatic suggestion should offer to rename it or move it to the correct place. Instead the suggestions only offer to change the package to a blank value, like it doesn't think the files are anywhere

Comment: But have you checked that the case is identical? That would be a better check than to rely on the suggested action from the IDE.

Comment: I've checked the case and they are definitely identical (all lower case in every instance)

Comment: 1) What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you running? If not the latest (v12.1.6), try upgrading. 2) Does the code compile (via IDEA's make) ok? 3) Try creating a separate simple project that has a package of the same name. It's remotely possible there is just a bizarre bug that is triggered by something in the package name.  (If there is, you can open a bug report at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com)